# WordpPess direct all sub-pages to a parent page

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am working with a page setup in WordPress, lets say `/clients`.

This page has a template assigned to it that outputs a list of clients from an **external database.**

What I want to do is to hyperlink each client to their own profile page e.g. `/clients/john-snow/`

Now because `/clients/john-snow/` is not a page that has been setup in WordPress, it will go to a 404 not found.

Does anyone know of a way that I can redirect all variations of `/clients/*` to reference another page or script where I can build the client profile?

I was thinking maybe using `.htaccess` to keep the URL as `/clients/john-snow/` but still point to `/clients/`

Comment: [Google Search Result](https://www.google.com.bd/search?newwindow=1&rlz=1C1KMZB_enBD539BD539&es_sm=122&q=wordpress+404+redirect+to+specific+page&oq=wordpress+redirect+404+for+speci&gs_l=serp.3.0.0i22i30.9166.11199.0.13178.10.10.0.0.0.0.354.1376.3j6j0j1.10.0....0...1c.1.45.serp..4.6.579.3KIitYwAEGA)

Comment: Yeah, Im thinking I'll need to do something along the lines of a 404 redirect. But I only want sub-pages of /clients/* to redirect to a specific page.

Answer (score 1):

You can [add a Rewrite Rule to parse query vars](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/7827/12615) in some specific URL.

```
add_action( 'init', 'rewrite_rule_so_23976696', 99 );

function rewrite_rule_so_23976696() {

    global $wp_rewrite;

    add_rewrite_rule( 'clients/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=clients&client_name=$matches[1]', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_tag( '%client_name%','([^&]+)' );

    if ( ! isset( $wp_rewrite->rules['^clients/(.+?)/?$'] ) )
        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();

}
```

And in your template file, something along the lines. If the URL contains `/clients/SOMETHING` do one thing, otherwise do the default thing.

```
$name = get_query_var('client_name');
if( $name ) {
    // Queried URL
    echo 'Something: ' . urldecode($name);
}
else {
    // Root URL
    echo 'Nothing.';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about replacing your WordPress .htaccess to be like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(clients/.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

The key is this line:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(clients/.*)$ [NC]
```

Which will exclude an URL request with `clients` in it.

**EDIT:** Re-reading your question it seems like you want to have a list of clients on `clients/` that is controlled in WordPress but then want to make sure that anything that is a child directory of that goes to whatever that page is. So I am pretty sure this solution won’t work for you. But maybe you can place the clients in another sub-path like `clients/content/` and then just change this `RewriteCond` to this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(clients/content/.*)$ [NC]
```

Which would allow you to have this WordPress controlled URL:

```
http://my.great.site/clients/
```

But also have this non-WordPress URL

```
http://my.great.site/clients/content/john-snow/
```

So in that way, `clients/` is still handled by WordPress, but since `clients/content/` is ignored, et voila!

Comment: I think this is what I am looking for. However I cant get it to work. Is there a RewriteCond that can make anything after /clients/ be treated as GET variable? so that /clients/john-doe/ would stay on the /clients/ page?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use this

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```